# calling one javascript function affecting two html drop download list

Tags: javascript, html

My question is can you call just one javascript function and affect two html drop down list the idea is to use the codes below

javascript code:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("cmbRecom")
```

html code:

```
<Select name="drop1" class="cmbRecom" >
        <option>Check Fields</option>                           
    </Select>

    <Select name="drop2" class="cmbRecom" >
        <option>Check Fields</option>                           
    </Select>
```

what is in my head, is the css behavior where you can name html elements with the same class names and all will follow that style that is declared for that class.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: call one javascript function and affect to html drop down list or select, example if you click a button the two drop down list will be populated, gets?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. One possible way is as follows:

```
document.documentElement.cmbRecomb;
```

Comment: good to know that it is possible sir, i already tried adding you code but right now it is not working can you check my JS function here it is                                                   function setCmbRecom(varArray)
{ 
   var setVarCmbRecom;
   setVarCmbRecom = varArray;
   var sel = document.documentElement.cmbRecom;
   for (var i in setVarCmbRecom) 
       { 
           var opt = document.createElement("option"); 
           opt.value = setVarCmbRecom[i]; 
           opt.text = setVarCmbRecom[i]; 
           sel.appendChild(opt); 
       }
}

Answer (score 0):

When selecting elements using the function `getElementsByClassName` the code should work with the returned elements as an array, which will require iteration through the selected elements.

```
var selects = document.getElementsByClassName("cmbRecom"); //was cmbField

for(var i = 0; i < selects.length; i++){
    selects[i].style.width = "200px";
}
```

**Note:** The class name and selector were different.

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/LWxcX/